# Acentuação incorreta ao gerar PDF

Tags: php, acentuação, fpdf

Após varias pesquisas na net, não consegui resolver meu problema com acentuação (charset).

Estou gerando uma relatório em FPDF e no campo descrição sai todo desconfigurado o texto:

[image: screenshot]

Já utilizei as funções `utf8_decode` e `utf8_encode` e verifiquei que a base MySQL está com o tipo de *charset* `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Como resolvo esse problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O FPDF usa codificação ISO-8859-1 ou Windows-1252, e teoricamente, como a *collation* do MySQL é latin1_swedish_ci as *strings* não precisam ser convertidas.

Se não funcionar sem a conversão é possível converter para Windows-1252 utilizando o código:

```
iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str), 'windows-1252', $str);
```

`mb_detect_encoding()` é utilizado para retornar o *charset* correto para `iconv()`, que faz a conversão.

Fonte: [FPDF utf-8 encoding (HOW-TO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9058876)

Comment: Obrigado Sanção, deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra forma e uft8_decode:

```
$pdf->Text (50,50,utf8_decode('Acentuação'));
```

Há modificações do FPDF como o TFPDF que já vem em UTF8:

https://github.com/rev42/tfpdf/blob/master/src/tFPDF.php

Comment: O problema disto é se o texto não estiver em utf8, a solução do Sansão, se você não testou ainda, seria interessante analise, ela verifica primeira a codificação atual e só depois converte, logo existem outros tipos de codificações que podem aparecer e o utf8_decode não vai resolver.

Comment: Uso isso nunca tive problemas....resolveu tudo....modifiquei o meu FPDF 1.81 com o TFPDF... outra coisa....a maioria dos editores de textos são UTF8...como notepad++

Comment: Entendo amigo, mas me refiro ao que não for utf8, pois existem muitas codificações além, e combinado o mb_detect_encoding+iconv fica mais smart.

Comment: Só acho que se tiver 50 linhas... repetir esse método não é muito bonito.... mesmo utf8_decode o ideal e alterar o FPDF para a sua necessidade. E ainda tem TCPDF que é uma alternativa...

Answer (score 0):

É sempre importante verificar o charset tanto na classe `domPDF`, `tcpdf`, `fPDF`... quanto no arquivo *php* que é gerado, no *html* e também nos dados recuperados do Banco de Dados. 
Não esqueça de setar no início do seu arquivo php:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Se sua classe geradora de PDF permitir, tente utilizar o `utf8_encode`, por exemplo, se seu HTML estiver armazenado em uma variável `$html`, aplique o encode como abaixo:

```
$html = utf8_encode($html);
$pdf->WriteHTMLCell(192,0,9,'',$html,0,1);//Nesse caso estou utilizando o tcpdf
```

Answer (score -4):

Segue abaixo instruções para  fixar o fpdf em utf8
Abra o arquivo `fpdf.php`

Procure a linha da Function Cell

que está assim

```
function Cell($w, $h=0, $txt='', $border=0, $ln=0, $align='', $fill=false, $link='')
```

depois de achar a linha

escreva depois do `{`,

```
$txt = utf8_decode($txt);
```

salve o arquivo e pronto, os acentos e a codificação utf8 estará funcionando.

Comment: Não é uma estratégia inteligente fazer alterações no código de módulos ou bibliotecas para solução de problemas simples. É problemático pois por se tratar de uma solução local e terá que ser aplicada a cada ambiente onde o código for rodado. Alterações ao esmo em módulos podem gerar efeitos colaterais imprevistos e de difícil depuração. Esse tipo de alteração é perdido durante o processo de atualização das dependências do sistema. Isso só deve ser feito em casos extremos, deve ser seguido de um fork e substituição da biblioteca original e sua remoção da lista de dependências do projeto.

Comment: Outro problema com essa solução é a função sugerida [`utf8_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-decode.php), se ler a documentação, logo no inicio está destacado **Aviso
Esta função tornou-se OBSOLETA a partir do PHP 8.2.0. O uso desta função é fortemente desencorajado.** mais abaixo é feita a nota **Nota : Obsolescência e alternativas
Esta função está obsoleta a partir do PHP 8.2.0 e será removida em uma versão futura. Os usos existentes devem ser verificados e substituídos por alternativas apropriadas.**