# Apache ISO-8859-1 + UTF8. É possível usar os dois ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: php, apache, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Sobre Apache com PHP em ISO-8859-1 + UTF8.

Tenho duas páginas em PHP com codificações distintas, sendo uma em ISO-8859-1 e outra em UTF8.

É possível usar as duas áginas com codificações distintas ao mesmo tempo no mesmo apache? Ou a única possibilidade que tenho seria separar em dois apaches distintos?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#/media/File:Utf8webgrowth.svg

Answer (score 2):

É perfeitamente possível trabalhar com vários *encodings* no mesmo servidor. Inclusive tenho feito isso com Apache e PHP faz um bom tempo, sem problemas.

Vale observar que para executar duas instâncias do Apache você precisaria de dois IPs diferentes, ou usar portas não-padrão.

Gosto muito de aproveitar as vantagens do ISO-8859-1, que é mais do que adequado para a Língua Portuguesa, e tem uma arquitetura extremamente simples e eficaz, o que não atrapalha em nada outras aplicações que usam UTF-8 no mesmo servidor.

Assim, enumerei alguns pontos a serem observados para você implementar na sua solução "multi-charset". Você pode reunir quase todos os conceitos em um `include` no início de todas as suas páginas, faciltando a manutenção.

Vamos lá:

### Definindo o padrão geral

Normalmente as configurações que determinam o padrão no Apache e no PHP são

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

e

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

Como o nome já diz em ambos os casos, esta é a configuração *default*, e só vale se o programador não disser de maneira explícita que quer algo diferente disto.

Uma vez que você não queira usar a codificação padrão sempre, que é o centro da pergunta, você pode ao menos facilitar um pouco, decidindo o que é regra e o que é exceção. Por outro lado, nada impede de explicitar tudo tanto nas aplicações UTF-8 quanto nas ISO-8859-1 (ou quaisquer outras).

Mas, convenhamos: se você tem 30 aplicações UTF-8, e duas diferentes disso, e seu padrão para aplicações futuras é UTF-8, convém deixar o UTF no *default*, e customizar apenas as ISO-8859-1 (e vice-versa, se sua base de trabalho é ISO, e UTF-8 as exceções).

Não vou entrar no mérito do que é melhor, pois quem diz que A ou B é o melhor encoding, mente (mesmo que inconscientemente). A verdade é que você conhecendo as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um (ambos os mencionados tem as duas coisas), vai usar o mais adequado para cada uma das suas aplicações.

### Explicitando o encoding

Uma vez que você tenha definido seu padrão, tem que considerar os vários pontos onde deve explicitar um encoding diferente dele.

#### *headers* e `meta tags`

A definição do encoding configurado no Apache é usada no envio dos cabeçalhos da página, neste formato:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Para mudar o encoding via PHP, a solução é esta:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

Desta forma, você está sobreescrevendo o *header* original com o novo valor. Além disso, pode explicitar no próprio HTML qual é o encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Importante saber que **não precisa** da meta-tag se já setou o *header*. Normalmente, a meta tag é usada em situações em que você não tem controle para mudar o *header* original (um HTML sem PHP, por exemplo), ou em situações que você queira que a página funcione bem se o usuário salvar uma cópia local (afinal, ao acessar a cópia local, normalmente nenhum *header* é setado)

#### *Encoding* da IDE/Editor de código

Fundamental que, ao salvar os códigos-fonte (seja PHP, HTML, JS) que contenham caracteres especiais, as preferências do documento estejam setadas para o *encoding* correto. Em alguns editores é uma das opções do "salvar como...", em outros você muda diretamente pela *statusbar*, ou menus. O importante é que esteja correto.

#### Enviando dados para a página

Normalmente, para mesclar dados vindos do DB com a página, se faz algo assim:

```
echo 'Nome do usuário: '.htmlentities( $user_name );
```

ou mesmo

```
Nome do usuário: <?= htmlentities( $user_name ) ?>
```

No seu caso, como serão sistemas em *encodings* diferentes, precisamos considerar a sintaxe original do [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php):

```
htmlentities( $string, $quote_style, $charset, $double_encode )
```

Se for omitido o `$charset`, ele assume o que foi configurado no `default_charset` do PHP. Então, no seu caso, é mais uma coisa a ser explicitada. Exemplo:

```
htmlentities( $user_name, ENT_COMPAT|ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8' )
```

Alternativamente, em vez de mexer em todas as ocorrências do `htmlentities` ou `htmlspecialchars` ou qualquer outra função que dependa do encoding), você pode usar no começo das páginas:

```
ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' ); // 'ISO-8859-1' conforme o caso
```

#### Interoperabilidade

Convém que tanto as conexões com a base de dados quanto os próprios dados estejam na mesma codificação das páginas, mas em muitas situações isto não é possível.

Além disso, quando se usam dados externos, como por exemplo num JSON, é normal que se precise dos dados em UTF-8 mesmo numa aplicação ISO-8859-1.

Para isto, o PHP tem estas funções:

- [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php), que converte especificamente de ISO-8859-1 para UTF-8;
- [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-decode.php), que converte especificamente de UTF-8 para ISO-8859-1.

**Importante:** estas funções só fazem sentido em contextos de interoperabilidade entre dois sistemas diferentes. Se forem usadas numa aplicação única, pode ser sinal de que algo está fundamentalmente errado.

#### Sistema de arquivos

Esta é uma recomendação que eu faria mesmo se a pergunta não tratasse de encoding. Não use caracteres acentuados nos nomes dos arquivos. Normalmente não há razão legítima para isso "só porque o sistema permite".

Uma coisa é você salvar um documento como "Currículo do Marcos.docx", que vai ser usado por pessoas, num editor de texto. Outra é querer fazer isso:

```
include('ÁlbumDeFotos.php');
```

No seu caso, mais importante ainda evitar, pois a linha acima será fatalmente entendida de maneira diferente para cada uma das aplicações, e seria totalmente dependente da configuração corrente do OS, e não mais do PHP nem do Apache.

Você acabaria precisando das funções de conversão mencionadas anteriormente, e o pior, se mudar sua aplicação de servidor, corre o risco de precisar revisar o código.

### Posts relacionados

[Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/70)

[Como configurar charset=utf-8 no Mysql?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139450/70)

[Problema com acentuação no FPDF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68878/70)